# Download email attachment bigger than 15 MB

Tags: stock-email-app

I got an email (MS Exchange 2010 / Native Mail App / LG G2 - 4.4.2 / connection->mobile-data[HSDPA]) with an PDF file with a size of ~18 MB.
When I click on it, it is trying to download it. After one second I got a message " was not downloaded".

When I am trying on an iPhone 5 (iOS 7.1) I can download and open the file.

Any work arounds or fixes for that issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the only work around for that problem is, to use this app -> CloudMagic (https://cloudmagic.com)

solved my problem but it would be reate when google will fix this for the stock email app.